# Why is res.writable never set to false even though it is a WritableStream?

Tags: node.js, httpresponse

The following seems like very awkward behavior to me:

- HTTP ServerResponse inherits from WritableStream
- Therefore, when `res.end()` is called, the `res.writable` boolean should be set to `false` as per the documentation:

**res.writable**

```
A boolean that is true by default, but turns false after an 'error' occurred or end() / destroy() was called
```

However:

```
console.log(res.writable); //true
res.end();
console.log(res.writable); //true
```

Now, how do I check if the respons has already been sent? The `req end event` is emitted when the request ends, not when a response is sent. The `res close event` is never emitted, there is only a `finish` event but this one is not documented and therefore unsupported.

Comment: You add a `res.ended` flag and check that.

Comment: @Raynos your reply does not answer the question.

Comment: then listen to the `"finish"` event. It's being standardized and documented in 0.10